# Extends a Flask template outside the Module Folder

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

For some reason I can't extends my base.html template.

My app structure

```
-app
|-- main
|     |-- __init__.py
|     |-- views.py
|-- templates
|     |-- main
|     |    |-home.html
|     |-- base.html
```

My app/main/views.py

```
from flask import (
Blueprint,
render_template
)

main_blueprint = Blueprint('main', 
                          __name__, 
                          template_folder='../templates/main'
                          )


@main_blueprint.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

My app/templates/base.html

```
<html> ...
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}      
</html>
```

My app/templates/main/index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Testing</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

When i try to running the app i got the error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: base.html
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix to get it work: Use `Flask(__name__, template_folder="../templates")` when you are creating app instance.

If you don't explicitly pass the template_folder for flask application it will look for `templates` in the same directory. In your case it is looking under main folder and Flask is unable to find any templates. There are some good opinionated ways of structuring flask app code. Please look into them and decide which works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your index is searching for main template inside a templates folder defined in template_folder parameter.

You can remove template_folder and pass a complete path from template like 'main/home.html'.