# {% extends 'NavigationEG/layout.html' %}

Tags: flask

in flask templates, we combine HTML pages using extends, but my view(HTML) files are in diff folder. so how u can extend that? how to set a path?  eg: {% extends 'NavigationEG/layout.html' %}  NavigationEG is my folder but this way not work

without a folder, it works but I want to store it in one folder.

Comment: So what did you try and encounter? Where did it fail?

Comment: layout.html not found.

Answer (score 0):

Like [bergp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6539270/bergbp) said in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59109562/extends-a-flask-template-outside-the-module-folder#:%7E:text=Your%20index%20is,main/home.html%27.) on stackoverflow, flask is looking for templates in the given templates folder. If you want to reference a different folder in your template, you could [remove the template_folder when initlializing the app](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask) and refering to the full path in the render_template parameters.

Depending on the reason for the different folders, [blueprints can have their own template_folder as well](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Blueprint).

I hope this helps. If not, please share your file structure and parts of the code so we can help you find the source of this problem. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, my folder is under templates then navigation then html file